# How to tell HttpServletRequest to use DatabaseServerLoginModule and no other?

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x

Something that I have not understood with JBoss AS (7.1.1 in my case) is how I can tell the HttpServletRequest object to employ the `DatabaseServerLoginModule` instead of the `UserNamePasswordLogineModule`. Here the executed code in my managed bean. I want the entire application (each HttpServletRequest object) to use the same realm, the same login module.

```
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();

        log.fine("A login request was issued from " + request.getRemoteHost()
                + ":" + request.getRemotePort());
        try {
            request.login(getUsername(), getPassword());
            if (request.isUserInRole("admin"))
                log.info("The logged in user is an administrator (admin)");
            else
                log.info("The logged in user is NOT an administrator (admin)");
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            log.warning("Failed to login with username (" + username
                    + ") and password. " + e.getMessage());
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                    "Login failed when tying to authenticate.", null));
            // If this fails, return null.
            return null;
        }
```

Here the realm configuration from my standalone.xml file

```
<security-domain name="ccmsSecurityDomain">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/CcmsDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM user WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM user JOIN user_role ON user.id = user_role.users_id JOIN role ON user_role.roles_id = role.id WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
                            <module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

**Why does it seem to pick on the `UsernamePasswordLoginModule`, too?** It seems it already has tried to check on `DatabaseServerLoginModule`.

```
23:19:29,542 DEBUG [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Bad password for username=admin
23:19:29,544 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.login(AuthenticatorBase.java:324) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:3252) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1082) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.hendrix.webapp.controller.security.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:202) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is correct, my configuration is **almost** correct.

I removed the hasing and encoding declaration in the standalone.xml file. and it worked fine.

```
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
<module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/>
<module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"/>
```

I need to re-investigate on the hashing separatly, but good to know that the login code connects properly to the database and validates the password.